# JavaScript method is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to learn JavaScript. As part of that effort, I am writing a basic minimax AI. I have the following methods:

```
Computer.prototype.expand = function(node) {
  /* adds all state action pairs to the node.successors array */
};

Computer.prototype.getMove = function(boardAr) {
  console.log("getMove");
  var b2 = boardAr.slice();
  var i;
  var action;

  this.root = new TNode(b2, this.mark);
  this.root.AIPlayedLast = false;
  this.expand(this.root);
  this.root.successors.forEach(this.minVal);
  action = maxNode(root.successors);
  this.draw(action);
  registerMove(action, this.mark);
};

Computer.prototype.minVal = function(node) {
  if (node.isTerminal) {
    return;
  } else { 
    this.expand(node);
    node.successors.forEach(maxVal);
    node.utility = this.minNode(node.successors).utility;
  }
};
```

When the `getMove` method is called the subsequent call to `expand` goes as expected. But, when `expand` is called from the `minVal` method I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I'm utterly perplexed by this. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, but as far as I know you should end each function with a semicolon, so after each } you should add ; -- Edit: tested, but doesn't change much, just a few syntax error will disappear

Comment: At first glance this looks fine ( although if you're writing a lot of this type of code you might want to look at combination constructors as it offers a tidier way of writing it - http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/ ) so the problem may arise in the way the code is called?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @briosheje why should you end each function with a semicolon?

Comment: It is an assignment statement; this should be terminated by a ';'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is in this row:

```
this.root.successors.forEach(this.minVal);
```

You pass minVal as contextless reference, it will not be called in a context of your Computer instance (this)

Here is how you can improve it:

```
var self = this;
this.root.successors.forEach(function() {
    self.minVal.apply(self,arguments);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and quickest solution is just to change

```
this.root.successors.forEach(this.minVal);
```

to

```
this.root.successors.forEach(this.minVal.bind(this))
```

This solves the problem in the same as the other answers, but in a way some might consider more  compact.

Or, you can pass a "this" to the `forEach` function as the second argument, a somewhat under-utilized feature of `forEach`:

```
this.root.successors.forEach(this.minVal, this)
```

This feature is also available on other `Array` prototype methods that take functions, including `map`, `filter`, `some`, `every` (but not `reduce` and `reduceRight`).

ES6 arrow functions handle `this` differently, so you can do

```
this.root.successors(forEach(e => this.minVal(e)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The forEach() method might be called for each of the successors. So, you pass the Computer::minVal method (this.minVal), but with the TNode(?) as this-pointer. Try:

```
var that = this;
this.root.successors.forEach(function(node) {
 that.minVal(node));
});
```